# Selecting a Random Card in Java

Tags: java, random

I'm new to java programming and have started creating a poker game. So far have have the cards and deck created but I want to be able to select a random card but I don't want to shuffle the deck.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PockerMain {

    public PockerMain() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<PokerCard> deck = cardDeck();
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.size(); i ++)
        {
            PokerCard card = deck.get(i);
            System.out.println(card);
        }

    }
    private static PokerCard createCard (short suit, short rank)
    {
        PokerCard card = new PokerCard (suit, rank);
        return card;
    }
    private static List<PokerCard> cardDeck ()
    {
        List<PokerCard> deck = new ArrayList<PokerCard> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j ++)
            {
                PokerCard card = createCard ((short)i, (short)j);
                deck.add(card);
            }

        }
        return deck;
    }
}
```

Comment: So [Random.nextInt(range)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) Should do the trick then.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Good questions on here show what you've tried and what problems you've encountered.  Your code so far sets up a deck, but I can't see any code attempting to select a random card - what have you tried so far?  What have you read / found out so far about generating a random number (say between 0 and 52) in Java?

Comment: I've managed to find a way round this including checking that it has removed the card from the deck so that when it deals a hand it doesn't give you the same card:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [Random.nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) which will give random number between 0 and n-1. So something like:

```
Random random = new Random();
int nextCardToPick = random.nextInt(deck.size());//get random number in range 0 - deck.size (assuming 52 cards then it will give value between 0 -51)
System.out.println(deck.get(nextCardToPick));//access by index
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using a Random object:
    PokerCard rCard = deck.get((int)(Math.random()*deck.size()));